# Get freed space when deleting files

Tags: powershell

I know that I can delete all files with specific extension recursively using a command like

```
get-childitem c:\ -include *.tmp -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

But what I must do in order to check freed space size after deleting files?

Comment: Get the amount of disk space before the above, run the above, then get the amount of disk space after. Subtract the second number from the first.

Comment: That would be the most accurate way. You already have access to the file size (the property is `length`) while in the loop so you could just add that up in the loop which would only require the one pass. However if a file was not deleted then you would have to add logic to account for that  possibility and it just make Bills suggestion a better fit.

Comment: If you want to know the amount of disk space freed by the deletions, I'd sum the length of the deleted files before they're deleted.  Checking disk freespace before and after doesn't account for any other process that   that may be adding or deleting files while you're doing your deletes.  If there's some other process running at the same time creating a large file, you could run your deletes, and have it report that you actually lost disk freespace.

Comment: You're right. This is the case why I don't like much these solutions because the windows machine is a server and other users can perform other file operations in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. You could use WMI before and after your code and check the difference. This could be considered a simpler approach.

```
$freeBefore = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object -Expand FreeSpace
...your code...
$freeAfter = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object -Expand FreeSpace

"Reclaimed {0:N4} MB of space" -f (($freeAfter - $freeBefore)/1MB)
```

**Note** in the above example I have hard coded the C: drive as the `DeviceID`. A caveat with this approach is that the space will be dependent on all computer operations at that time not just your own. Large file dumps that are unrelated to what you are doing would skew the numbers.

Another idea would be to calculate the size of change as you're processing the data since you would already have access to the `$file.length` (in bytes)

```
$total = 0 
$size = 0

Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $size = $_.length
    "Before $size"
    Try{
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
        $total += $size
    } Catch {
        "Could not remove $($_.FullName)"
    }
}

"Reclaimed {0:N4} MB of space" -f ($total/1MB)
```

The latter code has its faults. One being that this would report file content size but the size on disk which would be slightly larger for smaller files. If you have 1000's of tmp files that only take up 10 bytes the file data would be much smaller than size on disk which would be 4KB for each of them.

In either case you should account for errors as that is especially possible with files on the entire of your local disk. Tmp file could be open for writing by a program that you cannot delete. `-Force` can help but not always. You need to **be careful** running code like this.

Comment: Even if less precise I prefer the second solution. The windows machine is a server in whick files can be added/deleted in other places from other users, so it's possible that the size of free space after deletion can include other operations, while which this I can check the size of file that I delete.